# PHP json_encode is not working with ibase

Tags: php, json

Some part from my codes

```
$blstkodu = $row[1];

  $sqlisimcek = "select * from STOK where blkodu='$blstkodu'";
  $queryisimcek = ibase_prepare($sqlisimcek);
  $rsisimcek = ibase_execute($queryisimcek);
  $rowisimcek = ibase_fetch_row($rsisimcek);

  $stok_adi = $rowisimcek[2];


  $sql2 = "select * from STOK_FIYAT where blstkodu='$blstkodu' and alis_satis='2' and fiyat_no='1'";
  $query2 =  ibase_prepare($sql2);
  $rs2=ibase_execute($query2);
  $row2 = ibase_fetch_row($rs2);

  $fiyati = $row2[6];
  $hesap = $row2[4];



  $sonuc->stok_adi = $stok_adi;
  $sonuc->fiyati = $fiyati;
  $sonuc->hesap = $hesap;
  echo json_encode($sonuc);
```

This not working because I am using `json_encode`, but when I change to `echo` its working normally. How can I fix it?

By the way my code is working normally when if I am using MySQL database, but it's not working with ibase. Working code is this:

```
 $blkodu = $row['blkodu'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT fiyati,hesap FROM stok_fiyat WHERE blstkodu = '$blkodu' and alis_satis='2' and fiyat_no='1'";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


        $fiyati = $row2['fiyati'];
        $hesap = $row2['hesap'];

        $sonuc->stok_adi = $stok_adi;
        $sonuc->fiyati = $fiyati;
        $sonuc->hesap = $hesap;



      echo json_encode( $sonuc);
```

Comment: I've never used `ibase` but surely if you are preparing (`ibase_prepare`) then you shouldn't be passing values directly?

Comment: I would look in to debugging your code with [`ibase_errcode
`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-errmsg.php) and checking your error logs for anything.

Comment: And also maybe use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to tell you what went wrong with the encoding process. Perhaps you have some problematic characters in the data or something.

Comment: i think i know why not working. thank you @ADyson , i check problematic characters and i found. i need UTF8 with i base connection, how can i ?

Comment: sorry I don't know anything about ibase personally. Perhaps you can google and read some documentation, or someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: with utf8 ibaseconnect , everything is normal, thanks all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if ($db = ibase_connect('database.FDB', 'username', 'password','utf8'))
```

if you add UTF 8 into your connection string, everything is working normally, thanks all of you